# Pushing an image to a Docker repo crashes artifactory

Tags: artifactory

What reasons could there be that a push of a docker image to an Artifactory repo could crash the entire app?

The symptoms I see are that a layer hangs during the push:

```
» docker push my-repo/my-app:20211207-afdf6438-test
The push refers to repository [my-repo/my-app]
d4cde41bcf33: Layer already exists 
ac14050b2264: Layer already exists 
27e5cc646fd0: Pushing [==================================================>]  562.7MB
797b1ec2507f: Layer already exists 
34de87854e34: Layer already exists 
cde140fcdbee: Layer already exists 
be3883e87d34: Layer already exists 
9ec86c039eae: Layer already exists 
371ce8b24b31: Layer already exists 
7e718b9c0c8c: Layer already exists
```

It hangs on pushing that layer, then Artifactory becomes unresponsive until it finally restarts itself, which takes a while.

When this happens, the logs don't give me much to go on.

```
2021-12-09T20:06:01.066Z [jfrt ] [INFO ] [44ac995c9c11dc2e] [o.a.e.UploadServiceImpl:465 ] [http-nio-8081-exec-2] - Deploy to 'docker-local:my-app/_uploads/60766841-fac7-4781-b325-da9ef66ba2cf' Content-Length: 1 (estimation) artificial: false
2021-12-09T20:06:27.249Z [jfrt ] [INFO ] [ ] [ffectedConfigStreamObserver:32] [Stream_1639080147248] - publishing full invalidation and attempting to resubscribe to affected configuration changes
2021-12-09T20:06:28.145Z [jfrt ] [INFO ] [ ] [ffectedConfigStreamObserver:32] [Stream_1639080153144] - publishing full invalidation and attempting to resubscribe to affected configuration changes
2021-12-09T20:06:29.646Z [jfrt ] [INFO ] [ ] [ectedEntitiesStreamObserver:35] [Stream_1639080154645] - publishing full invalidation and attempting to resubscribe to affected permissions changes
2021-12-09T20:07:26.615Z [jfrt ] [ERROR] [59398681a5a1be14] [o.j.a.c.h.AccessHttpClient:136] [http-nio-8081-exec-6] - Error while executing /api/v1/users/ on access. Exception message: Read timed out
2021-12-09T20:07:51.686Z [jfrt ] [ERROR] [6a934e4bf3e126b4] [o.j.a.c.h.AccessHttpClient:136] [http-nio-8081-exec-4] - Error while executing /api/v1/users/ on access. Exception message: Read timed out
2021-12-09T20:07:56.622Z [jfrt ] [ERROR] [2fe4c5688866ed57] [o.j.a.c.h.AccessHttpClient:136] [http-nio-8081-exec-8] - Error while executing /api/v1/users/ on access. Exception message: Read timed out
2021-12-09T20:07:56.622Z [jfrt ] [ERROR] [2b94004eb23bb041] [o.j.a.c.h.AccessHttpClient:136] [ttp-nio-8081-exec-12] - Error while executing /api/v1/users/ on access. Exception message: Read timed out

Terminating Artifactory
```

This is self-hosted Artifactory 7.27.10 running in Kubernetes

Comment: This could be a result of too little CPU and memory resources for Artifactory. How is it running? What resources did you give it? Does it able to accept a smaller docker image if you push it?

Comment: Good suggestion, but it has plenty of CPU and memory, and doesn't come close to using it all.

Comment: But how much is it? If you clustert has a lot of memory and cpu, that does not mean your container has it all. You have to ser resources requests and limits. Try setting 8Gi of memory request and limit along with 4 CPU. Also, make sure you allocate at least 4g of java Xmx (it can be set in the values.yaml)

Comment: 8Gi with xmx 6, 2 CPU.

Comment: The `Terminating Artifactory` message implies this was a termination singnal sent to the container. Due to a filing liveness probe or a K8s OOM event. Can you look at the pod's events and errors to get some clues? Also - are you able to push a smaller image to Artifactory?

Comment: It is failing healthchecks, and the site becomes unresponsive right after I get those `publishing full invalidation and attempting to resubscribe to affected configuration changes` logs. I just discovered that I can't even generate a support bundle, lol. Not that I have support, I was just going to look at them myself.

Comment: How did you install artifactory? Any special configuration?

Comment: As generic as it could be. external postgres database, s3 filestore. Nothing unusual.

Comment: 2 cpu might be throttling your services. I suggest increasing to 4 or even more. What about pushing a smaller image? Does that work?

Answer (score 1):

This was a disk performance problem. I use EFS for my Artifactory data volume. For some reason still unknown to me, Artifactory started requiring higher IOPS than the EFS volume could provide. I was able to solve the problem by changing the EFS volume to provisioned IOPS.

Pulls worked fine, because my backing datastore is s3. So the problem only manifested on pushes, after all the docker layers were uploaded, and when log files were written to the EFS volume. It was on log writes that the system choked and restarted.

Comment: Glad to hear! Thanks for sharing the solution for others to enjoy. Consider using the S3 direct upload (https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/S3+Object+Storage#S3ObjectStorage-ConfiguringArtifactorytoUseS3) which will help reducing pressure on local disk. You can eventually drop EFS and just use a simple EBS or even an emptyDir for local config and cache.

Comment: I’m using EFS because it’s non-zonal. I have a small cluster and I can’t count on a node being available in a specific AZ, so I don’t use EBS for that reason.